# Is there a global shortcut to access the application preferences of an active application?

Tags: 12.04, shortcuts, preferences

The application preferences in the menu options do not show a shortcut for fast access.

I'd like to have a unified shortcut to access the applications preferences in any application.
How can I get a **shortcut for the application preferences** of the active application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not really possible since it would require all applications to follow the same guidelines for using shortcuts. And obviously they do not.

Most programs will get you to preferences with <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>e</kbd> but the next letter is different in various programs. 
Some examples ...

- You get to preferences for Nautilus and Firefox with <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>e</kbd>, <kbd>n</kbd> (prefereNces). P is for Paste but the letter seems to be different since `f` looks available)
- If you want to reach preferences on Chrome it is <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>e</kbd>, <kbd>s</kbd> (for Settings) and then shows you the inline settings from the icon in Chrome. The **P** accesses Paste (Preferences does not have a letter and you might even consider this a bug: the text should have been named Settings).
- Shutter on the other hand has <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>e</kbd>, <kbd>p</kbd> (Preferences).
- Terminal is even more weird: it uses <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>e</kbd>, <kbd>o</kbd> for prOfile preferences.
- Preferences in USC is called Software sources.

You might be able to track down all the text segments in the software but that would be time consuming and temporary: the 1st time you update you might overwrite all your changes. The path you can take to get what you want could be to file bugs against alle applications that do not use for instance the method Nautilus and Firefox use. Seems impossible to me to get done.

Comment: Thanks! You understood my question correctly :) I've tried your shortcut for Firefox, but this seems to work only partially. I.E. When I hold ALT, I first need to need to select the parent menu where "preferences" is located. A direct access to the application preferences then requires **ALT+B+E**.

Comment: Press alt, hold it and press e. That opens Edit. The n opens preferences for FF. Ofcourse I tried it first before I typed it ;-) (alt+b goes to bookmarks)

Comment: Would HUD help?

Comment: I think the HUD actually has some potential to solve this problem. I drafted this [Ubuntu brainstorm idea](http://brainstorm.ubuntu.com/idea/30715/) to create a spec for future apps and hack the old ones through the HUD interface (DBUS, I guess?).